# Is there a way to know how many volatile messages are dropped with Socket.IO on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, volatile

I searched a bit around and didn't find nothing about this particular issue. I am currently developing something that involves Socket.IO on Node.js.

My question is pretty simple : is there a way to know how many messages are dropped from a socket.volatile.emit() ?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/transport.js#L524-534

No counter incremented, but you could turn on logging to take a look.

Comment: I managed to find a way to count failed messages VS success messages, but it's a bit complex to get the reference of the transport :

io.sockets.manager.transports[socket.id]

Comment: Finally, more I think about this issue in my project, more I think it's useless to count or to know this kind of stuff. At least, we know it's possible! Thanks for the help! :)